# My Select form is not displaying database items

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a form where the user can insert a product into a database. One of the the things they must input is the category, which I am using a select input form to allow them to choose from the available categories (PHP and MySQL displays all the available categories). The options inside the select element is given with PHP. But for some reason, when I run the application, the categories do not show up. No errors or anything, and the connection to the database is assured. The code is below. I am using the MVC pattern, if that helps any

The file with the function (category_db.php)

```
<?php

function get_categories() {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY categoryID";
    $statement= $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    return $statement;
}
```

The controller for the files (index.php)

```
<?php
require ('../models/database.php');
require ('../models/product_db.php');
require ('../models/category_db.php');


$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');

if($action == NULL || $action==FALSE){
    $action = 'list_products';
}




if ($action == 'list_products'){
    $categories = get_categories();


    $category_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'category_id');
    if ($category_id == NULL || $category_id == FALSE){
        $category_id = 1;
    }

    $product_item = get_product_list($category_id);
    include ('product_list.php');


} else if ($action = 'delete_product') {
    $product_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_id');
    $category_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category_id');
    delete_product($product_id);
    header("Location: .?category_id=$category_id");

}
else if($action == 'add_product'){
    $categories = get_categories();
    include('add_product_form.php');
}
```

And finally, the page that display the form (add_product_form.php)

```
<?php include '../includes/header.php'; ?>

<main>
    <h3>Add Product Form</h3>
    <form method="post" action=".">
        <label for="category">Category</label>

           <select name="category">
        <?php foreach ( $categories as $category ) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $category['categoryID']; ?>">
                <?php echo $category['categoryName']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        </select>


        <br>

        <label for="product_code">Product Code</label>
        <input type="text" name="product_code"><br>

        <label for="product_name">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="product_name"><br>

        <label for="list_price">List Price</label>
        <input type="text" name="list_price"><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Add Product">
    </form>
</main>


  <?php include '../includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Now I have triple checked the code, but I cannot find the problem. Any help on this would be appreciated. I am also using netbeans if that helps any

Comment: you have not include `product_add.php` in `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a "fetchAll" in your function so you will return an array with all your categories :

```
 function get_categories() {
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY categoryID";
    $statement= $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();

    $categories = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $categories;
}
```

Then you can loop throught the array to get the data you want.

Comment: The weird thing is that using this function in the exact same way worked on another page. I was just display them as links, and it worked, but I will try and do a fetch all

Comment: Can you check what you get with your function get_categories() with and without the fetchAll()?